# Different Multiselectable field django

Tags: python, django

I want a different multiselectable field(m2m) that brings Django because is not very usable for many values, something like a dropdown that allow to search and select the value to be displayed in a list, is there a django package that allow me to change the style of the field? or can you give me a recomendation for solving my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack Overflow isn't a great place to ask for suggestions that are very broad or primarily opinion-based. However, you will want to take a look at [Select2](https://select2.github.io/).

It is framework-agnostic, highly configurable and can do everything you described in your question.

Comment: Great, thanks, as you said it is what I was searching for